# xGBoost and Catboost in pycaret

Tags: xgboost, catboost, pycaret

I'm going to use pycaret for a regression problem.
Although according to its tutorials (here: [regression tutorial/ beginner level](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Regression%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20REG101.ipynb) ) models such as xgboost and catboost are available in the package, I can not recall them in my colab environment.
How can I fix this problem?

Note: As I said, I'm running my code in the google colab and these are my codes:

```py
!pip install --pre pycaret
# after the above line you should restart your runtime
from pycaret.regression import *
# here, I give my data to the setup
setup (data = data, target = price)
models()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. I could resolve the problem.
You must enter the below code to recall all functions in pycaret:

```py
!pip install pycaret[full]
```